# Tag Wikis: Guidelines for Resource Relevance?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I recently made some updates to the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag wiki, and discovered that a lot of the resources are stale, if not out-of-date. For example, Sean Sexton's [2,000 Things You Should Know About C#](https://csharp.2000things.com/) blog hasn't been updated in seven years. This is especially notable in the books section, where new editions have been *appended*, not *replaced*, and some relate to previous versions of the language:

> **Books**
>
> - Head First C# ([3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449343503), [4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491976705))
> - The C# Programming Language ([3rd Edition](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321562992), [4th Edition](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321741765))
> - Framework Design Guidelines ([2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613), [3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135896460/))
> - Essential C# ([6.0 (5th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134141040), [7.0 (6th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1509303588), [8.0 (7th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135972264/))

I should note that I've contributed to this practice myself, in [my recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3607007/178), since I wanted to maintain consistency with the status quo (see [Chesterton's Fence](https://fs.blog/2020/03/chestertons-fence/)).

#### Question

I know we have [editorial guidelines for writing a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one). But do we have any established thresholds for when resources should be removed? Acknowledging that some books remain relevant for years (e.g., those related to software architecture), while others are much more time-limited (e.g., those that are version specific).

#### Notes

While I'm using [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) as an example, ideally this would apply to *any* tag. That said, I browsed the top 20 tags, and most seem much better maintained. I'm happy to cleanup the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, but I wanted to check with the community before bulk removing old blogs and book editions. I'll leave my proposal as an answer, so it can be voted on independently of the broader question.

Answer (score -1):

My inclination is to apply the following heuristics:

#### Blogs

- Remove if the blog hasn't been updated at least once in the last year.

#### Books

- Only include the latest edition that's relevant to the specific tag; remove previous editions.
- Move outdated version-specific editions to the relevant version-specific tag, if available (e.g., [c#-8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-8.0)).
- Remove non-version-specific introductory books that are over five years old (e.g., [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454), from 2012).
- Remove any books that have not maintained at least a 4.0 rating on Amazon (e.g., [C# 7 Quick Syntax Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FLNKGZ5), at 2.5/5.0).
- Solicit feedback from e.g. MSO or SME chat rooms before removing non-version-specific architectural books (e.g., [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), from 1994).

Comment: I understand and agree with you that the goal of removing listed resource links should be to keep the list as useful and high-quality as possible; on the other hand, some of the thresholds and criteria you've listed feel really... *arbitrary*. I feel like resources should be ditched or kept based on their usefulness alone, not age or Amazon star-count, though I do understand that both of those metrics can *imply* quality (or lack thereof).

Comment: @zcoop98: Agreed. I definitely struggled to come up with something meaningful for the last three points. I feel much more confident in the first two.

Comment: @zcoop98: Additionally, while these thresholds generally hold up for the areas of technology I'm involved in, I also recognize that they may be poorly calibrated based on that bias. For example, I could imagine that a six year old [tag:html] book might still be relevant, whereas a six year old book on [tag:.net] is probably quite dated, based on how many new versions have been released in that time.

Comment: I would drop the 4th entry (Amazon rating): An arbitrary threshold on an arbitrary external website does not seem like a good criteria. Judge the book yourself and/or ask in the chat rooms. For the 3rd entry: 5 years should really be reworded to be technology dependent.

Comment: "*Remove if the blog hasn't been updated at least once in the last year.*" I'd caution against this. There are some things that are eternally useful/applicable, or at least useful/applicable for *far* longer than one year. There are posts on Joel Spolsky's blog or Jon Skeet's blog, for example, that are likely eternally useful blog posts; even if they were to keel over dead tomorrow, a year or two from now the value of their blogs would not change.

Comment: Last updated is irrelevant, some blogs and books are timeless. Not everyone needs or likes the newest shiny tech. Sorry but I think all these metrics are unhelpful. I mean this in the best possible way, but if a reviewer needs to rely on things like "it's X years old" or "has 4 amazon stars" and can't evaluate this on a case by case basis, please don't review. Remove wrong information, keep correct information. Make a meta topic about each point of disagreement if you have to, but it's not as simple as "everything older than 1 year is wrong", *that* is an incorrect statement.